# TYPO3 Is this possible to remove add content button from backend for specific custom layout

Tags: typo3, typo3-11.x

My typo3 version is 11.5.10.

I want to remove the `+ Content` button for specific column of our page layout:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The extension [bootstrap_package](https://extensions.typo3.org/extension/bootstrap_package) is using a field like that and the trick is just to omit `colPos` in the backendlayout.

[image]

In the following code you can see that in the one defined column `colPos` is just missing:

```
                            3 {
                                columns {
                                    1 {
                                        name = LLL:EXT:bootstrap_package/Resources/Private/Language/Backend.xlf:backend_layout.column.subnav
                                        colspan = 3
                                    }
                                    2 {
                                        name = LLL:EXT:bootstrap_package/Resources/Private/Language/Backend.xlf:backend_layout.column.left
                                        colPos = 1
                                        colspan = 3
                                    }
                                    3 {
                                        name = LLL:EXT:bootstrap_package/Resources/Private/Language/Backend.xlf:backend_layout.column.normal
                                        colPos = 0
                                        colspan = 6
                                    }
                                }
                            }
```

For the case you want to look up by yourself, it's in the TypoScript-template `bootstrap_package/Configuration/TsConfig/Page/Mod/WebLayout/BackendLayouts/subnavigation_left_2_columns.tsconfig`.

This solution works without any additional extension or PHP code.

Answer (score 1):

That's not possible with TYPO3 core.

you might disable all possible CEs for that column if you use an additional extension: [`content defender`](https://extensions.typo3.org/extension/content_defender/)

At least you can assign a column number where you skip the rendering in the front end.

Comment: Where to assign a column number ???

Comment: @ChetanShah No need to assign a column number for content defender.

In the column which has the label "Left" in your configuration add empty CType under allowed. This should make users unable to add any content elements under column 1. Example https://github.com/IchHabRecht/content_defender

Comment: Regret having to say that it's possible, see my answer.

Comment: Anyway, the link to content_defender is quite interesting, so your answer is still useful.